# Accessing Jamon monitoring on Wildfly shows 403/Forbidden

Tags: wildfly, jamon

I'm trying to deploy the newest version of Jamon on the newest version of wildfly. You can download the versions here:

[Wildfly 8.1.0](http://download.jboss.org/wildfly/8.1.0.Final/wildfly-8.1.0.Final.zip)

[Jamon 2.79](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jamonapi/files/)

To get the .war deployed you need to include the 'jamon-279.jar' into the lib-Folder of the 'jamon.war' file.

After wildfly deployed jamon i'm trying to access with

> localhost:8080/jamon/

But this gives me a a 403 Forbidden screen. I changed nothing neither in web.xml of jamon nor in standalone.xml. Both are standard configurations.
The log shows me only this line everytime i'm trying to access:

```
PBOX000354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

AFAIK in the default settings the security constraint should be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue. Jamon deploys and can be accessed without problems.

You could try enabling `TRACE` logging for `org.picketbox` to find out more about why access is denied in your environment.